# Typeorm insert querybuilder orIgnore throws error

Tags: mysql, orm, typeorm

I am trying to insert some data and ignore it if it conflicts.

this should be my typeorm query

```js
        await this.dataSource
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .insert()
          .into(XmlInterfaceFile, ['file_name'])
          .orIgnore()
          .values([{ file_name: name }])
          .execute();
```

That generates the following SQL

```sql
INSERT  IGNORE INTO `xml_interface_file`(`file_name`) VALUES (?) -- PARAMETERS: ["SomeFile.txt"]
```

That is exactly what I want , unfortunately typeORM throws the following error:

> TypeORMError: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.

That error originates [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a909d5b6975f0feb0c8759dd146dba8f1e3ad168/src/query-builder/ReturningResultsEntityUpdator.ts#L87).

Is there a way to sidestep it ? I will probably resort to selecting and updating if not.